# Setting deeply nested object in Redux reducer not propagating updates to my component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am trying to set a deeply nested object in my react.js/redux app via a reducer, but the object changes are not propagating down to my component. How should I update and mapStateToProps an object like this?

I have tried ...ing my action's payload in my reducer, mapping a higher level object in my mapStateToProps, and flattening the object I map to my components props.

My initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    myObject : {
        prop1 : {
            prop2 : {
                array1 : [],
                array2: [],
                array3: []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My reducer:

```
const app = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        myObject: action.payload
      };
  } default:
      return state;
}

export default app;
```

My Component:

```
class Component extends React.PureComponent() {
    render() {
        return (
            {
                JSON.stringify(this.props.componentObject)
            }
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        componentObject: state.myObject
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

Action creator for updating nested object

```
export function setData(newDeeplyNestedObject) {
  return {
    type: SET_DATA,
    payload: newDeeplyNestedObject
  };
}
```

The result is that my Component is not displaying what is in Redux's state. It appears that the Redux is not detecting a change in my components props thus not updating the Component. Can anyone tell me how  to make sure Redux sends updates to my component when a deeply nested object structure changes?

I know that Redux does a shallow compare for updates, but I feel like a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) in my reducer is not the right direction here.

Comment: your `mapStateToProps` is incorrect, `myObject` is inside `state.app` but you are looking for it in `state`. You need to do: `componentObject: state.app.myObject`

Answer (score 0):

1) Implement a store by:
    
    `import {createStore} from "redux";
    export const store = createStore(app) // you pass in your reducer name`

2) In mapStateToProps, access your myObject state like:
     
      `function mapStateToProps(state){ 
        return{
        myObject:state.myObject`
    } 
  };

3) Bind your action dispatcher:

```
   import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>(bindActionCreators({setData}, dispatch));
   //Now we can use the setData action creator as this.props.setData()
```

4) Use both mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps and connect it to the component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

5) Suppose you defined myObjects in INITIAL_STATE, for example:

```
    myObject : {
        prop1 : {
            prop2 : {
                array1 : [{a:'1'},{b:'2'}],
                array2: [{q:'6'},{w:'4'}],
                array3: [{m:'9'},{n:'0'}]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

6) Now you need to **fire your action** function setData using any changeHandlers or button press and pass the newObject which you wanna add as arguments. The idea is to spread the objects(using the **... operator**) and append the new items which you wanna add. Suppose you wanna fire your action on an onClick event and change the array1 values:

```
<input type="button" onClick={()=>this.props.setData({...this.props.myObject.prop1.prop2,array1:[{changedA:'21'},{changedB:'32'}]})}/>
```

This will fire the action, and only the array1 will be changed. Similarly, you can do for any nested objects.
**Whatever change you want to do, you have to spread your objects and then append the new items**

PS: Also enclose the return in  tags.